# We just moved a wordpress installation and need .htaccess redirects

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

old URI's that would have to be redirected...

http://www.domain.com/  -> http://www.newdomain.com/

http://domain.com/ -> http://newdomain.com/

Now I got this to work, sort of with

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but now I'm dealing with wordpress permalinks AND the fact that we moved from a subdirectory to the root.

http://domain.com/blog/2013/11/25/los-angeles-pop-trash-street-tweety-zippy-2/

is now

http://newdomain.com/los-angeles-pop-trash-street-tweety-zippy-2/

and this doesn't work at all

```
RewriteRule /blog/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*) http://newdomain.com/$4 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

any suggestions on how to do the .htaccess rewrite so that we can do the 301 redirects on the default domains and the permalinks?

TIA.

Comment: Try to login inside your WP admin area at new domain, then switch the permalinks to the `Default`, WP will regenerate the correct rules in the `.htaccess` file, after that switch again the permalinks to your desired option.

Answer (score 0):

I always use a plugin called [Velvet Blues Update URL's](http://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/) to change all the old url links to my new url links whenever I move from live to test site and vise-versa. This saves you the headaches that you get with rewriting etc.

Just download and install it, enter your old url, new url, check all boxes and click "Update URL's". Update your permalinks afterwards. Just remember, ALWAYS MAKE A BACK-UP FIRST

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it, you were missing a `^` at the start of the rule. Try

```
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*) http://newdomain.com/$4 [R=301,L,QSA]
```